# How to query dataframe rows to API requests.post?

Tags: python, dataframe, api, rest, python-requests

With `requests.post` method, I am trying to send a query (sentences in `df` rows) to an API to get responses. The API is supposed to calculate the similarity of a sentence (my query) with other text in the API and return the top 10 most similar sentences. My code works when the search query dictionary contains only one sentence (as below):

```
search_query = {'input': 'sentence'}

api_response = requests.post("https://api.com/login", json=login_request)
api_response = requests.post("https://api.com/login/sentence_semantic", json = search_query, headers = headers)
```

The API then returns top 10 results for each sentence. It means each sentence is associated with top 10 similar sentences ranked.

But my input data for the *search_query* is a `dataframe` of many rows with two columns: *Column_ID*, *Column_Sentence*.

How should I formulate the *search_query* based on my `dataframe` and keep the records of responses associated to each individual row of `dataframe`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over your dataframe as below, assuming your dataframe name is df:

```
for row in df['Column_Sentence']:
    response = requests.post("https://api.com/login", json=login_request)
    response = requests.post("https://api.com/login", json = {"input": row}, headers = headers)
    results = response.json()
```

results is a json output and you need to process is further by selectiong keys and values. the keys are corresponding to each queried row in your initial dataframe.